# %0D Carriage return appended in bash file

Tags: bash, unix

I have a bash file where I have

```
wget https://packages.chef.io/files/stable/chef-server/12.15.7/ubuntu/14.04/chef-server-core_12.15.7-1_amd64.deb
```

When I do a cat I dont't see %0D appended at the end but when I execute this bash script I see

```
--2017-05-30 05:13:59--  https://packages.chef.io/files/stable/chef-server/12.15.7/ubuntu/14.04/chef-server-core_12.15.7-1_amd64.deb%0D
```

How to execute this script removing the carriage return?

Comment: can you check your script with `cat -A script.sh`

Comment: It has lots of `^M$` in it. Almost after every line

Comment: In that case remove `^M` using `dos2unix` command or using `sed` as this: `sed -i 's/\r//' script.sh`

Comment: This removed all `^M` but not `$`

Comment: Yes `$` indicates end of line character not any additional character. Your file is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using `cat` command on a .txt in a script.

```
for file in $(cat myfile.txt)
```

The output was, for each iteration, a line of `myfile.txt` followed by `%OD`. I solved the issue by applying `dos2unix` to my file

```
dos2unix mytext.txt
```

If you do it to you script maybe it could fix it.